# Can get some values in JSON by key, others I cannot get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON:

```
[{
  "cityid":101,
  "city":"Alta"
},
{
  "cityid":102,
  "city":"Bluffdale"
},
{
  "cityid":105,
  "city":"Draper"
},
{
  "cityid":107,
  "city":"Holladay"
}]
```

I can successfully search this array, and get the "city" value, with this function:

```
function getLocality(cid){
    var storedlist = localStorage.getItem("citylist");
    var clist = JSON.parse(storedlist);
    for(var i = 0; i < clist.length; i++)
    {
        if(clist[i].cityid == cid) {
            return clist[i].city;
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

**My Issue:**

When I try to use another function to get the city, instead of getting the cityid, it does not work.

The function I am using to try and get the city id, is as follows:

```
 function getCityid(cid){
    var storedlist = localStorage.getItem("citylist");
    var clist = JSON.parse(storedlist);
    for(var i = 0; i < clist.length; i++)
    {
        if(clist[i].city == cid) {
            return clist[i].cityid;
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the function as so:

```
getCityid('Draper');
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show exactly how you are calling `getCityid`?

Comment: Use either a debugger or add some `console.log` lines to determine what the value of `cid` is before you try to compare to the city list item. Possibly it's not in the same case. Are you certain `cid` in the second case is indeed a city or are you still trying to compare to an id string?

Comment: Post is updated. I am using a debugger (console.log specifically) to do this. I have another function making sure that the first letter of every word is UpperCase. I am positive it is a city, and I am trying to get the code to take a city, and return a cityid.

Comment: Not to be "that" guy but how is this related to PHP? Or jQuery, for that matter?

Comment: What does it actually return, and are there any errors?

Comment: I don't see any problem with this: See [a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p488a3zd/) with the code you posted. I would think it would be an error with inputting it to `localStorage`, but your first function works, so I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Yeah, this looks totally fine. What is getting returned that is different than what you expect?

Comment: I am getting a return of "undefined". Or if I put return 'nomatch' into the else clause, then I get nomatch. The jfiddle shows the code is correct. I am unsure why exactly it isn't working.

Comment: There had to be an whitespace, or character error of sorts in my text editor. I copied it from Jfiddle, and now it works. Thanks guys!

Comment: Works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wpev7chs/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just opened up the console and tried both of your functions and they both seem to work. Since you didn't provide any sample input/output of your issue, I'll recommend the following:

1. Verify that you're passing in correct parameters into each function. The `getLocality()` should take in a `cityid` and `getCityid()` should take in a `city`.
2. Refrain from using `==` in javascript as this operator performs type coercion wherein things which are disparate types are "forced" to be the same type in order to perform comparison. You should instead use the `===` operator which will not perform type coercion. If the two things being compared are different types, it will simply evaluate to false.

Comment: Thank you! Finally figured out the issue. It must have been a whitespace and or character issue of some sort. When I copied it from jfiddle, it works now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function getCityid(city) {
  var storedlist = localStorage.getItem("citylist");
  var clist = JSON.parse(storedlist);
  for(var i = 0; i < clist.length; i++){
      if(clist[i].city === city) {
          return clist[i].cityid;
      }
   }
}
```